# How can I be sure that my data is stored in elgg database?

Tags: database, elgg

I have usersettings directory in my plugin that add automatically configure your tools section. users can create secret and qrcode of this secret.
I wrote action for saving secret and when click save button the secret have been saved in textbox.
how can I be sure that my secret is stored in database?Does anyway to see it in database?Is there in metadata?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to database manually and see for yourself using ie. phpmyadmin or mysql cli interface. Look at table private_settings

Alternatively you can just use `elgg_get_plugin_user_setting` to dump the setting value.